Integration with PlayIntegrity Api and GoogleAuth results in 403 Forbidden Error
I am trying to Integrate Play Integrity Api in my Android app,
I have deployed my android app to Internal testing and also enabled in Google play console as shown in below screenshot

Here is the sample code for my android app
val integrityTokenResponse = integrityTokenProvider.request(
                StandardIntegrityTokenRequest.builder()
                    .setRequestHash(hash)
                    .build()
            )
            integrityTokenResponse.addOnSuccessListener { response ->
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    val apiResponse = retrofit.verifyHash(VerifyHashRequest(response.token()))
                    runOnUiThread {
                        textView.text = apiResponse.message
                    }
                }
                     }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Failure ${exception.message}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

Now the verifyHash calls my backend api, here is my code for the backend api for which I am using node.js
import { GoogleAuth } from "google-auth-library";
import path from "path";
 
 const {
      token,
    }: {
      token: string;
    } = await request.json();
  
    const keyFilePath = path.resolve(
      "./my.json"
    );

    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: keyFilePath,
      scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/playintegrity"],
    });
    const packageName = "myandroidpackagename";

    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const accessToken = await client.getAccessToken();
    const url = `https://playintegrity.googleapis.com/v1/${packageName}:decodeIntegrityToken`;

    console.log("token", token);
    console.log("accessToken", accessToken.token);
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken.token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        integrityToken: token,
      }),
    });

    console.log("response", response);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }

    const json = await response.json();

    return Response.json({
      message: JSON.stringify(json),
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return Response.json({
      message: "Error " + e,
    });
  }

Now I have replaced myandroidpackagename with my proper android package name,
In google play console I have linked my Google cloud project
and in my Google cloud project I have enabled  Google Play Integrity API

In My Google Cloud Project, I have enabled Service accounts and downloaded the json file which I am referring as my.json in the above node.js code
I am able to see token and accessToken being printed but the response gives error saying
{
  status: 403,
  statusText: 'Forbidden',
  headers: Headers {
    vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    date: 'Sun, 29 Dec 2024 08:19:31 GMT',
    server: 'ESF',
    'content-length': '154',
    'x-xss-protection': '0',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000'
  },
  body: ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: true },
  bodyUsed: false,
  ok: false,
  redirected: false,
  type: 'basic',
  url: 'https://playintegrity.googleapis.com/v1/myapppackage:decodeIntegrityToken'
}

What else is missing?
